# How can I drive a 14-segment alphanumeric display?

Tags: pic, display

I am trying to use a common anode 14-segment dual-digit alphanumeric display using a PIC16F877A. As far as I can find online, the MAX6955 pops up everywhere. It looks like a complicated chip to work with as I am new to the PIC environment.  Not having the advantage of Arduino library is really making things difficult. The MAX6955 is $22.42 per chip which is quite expensive for what I want to do. Is there any alternative to drive a 14-segment display?

The display is an [HDSP-A2xC](https://docs.broadcom.com/doc/HDSP-A2xC-DS), 14-segment dual-digit alphanumeric display, common anode, two pairs.

Comment: How much current does it need?

Comment: @winny According to the [datasheet](https://docs.broadcom.com/doc/HDSP-A2xC-DS) the typical should be about \$30\:\text{mA}\$. To Ankit, I have boxes of MAX6955's. Got them a LOT cheaper than what you quote. No idea why they are going for so much, today. I should sell them, I suppose, and make a killing. ;) Or wait a little longer and make a bigger killing?

Comment: ON semi CAT9532 or any other IO expander for LED driving?

Comment: Ankit, the old-days approach to this would be to use a "1 of 2 scanner" (or just two pins of the MCU plus 2 BJTs) and a BCD to 7-segment decoder (or use more MCU pins, if not) followed by a 7-segment driver chip (or, again, some BJTs.) Are you willing to kind of 'go discrete' on this? Or stuck with the idea of using boutique ICs (which in today's market appear to command some kind of price due to chip shortages?) If you are comfortable and set up to program the PIC16F877A (I would use assembly code) then you can just write yourself application code and make your own solution IC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The smallest package of that PIC exposes 22 general purpose port pins - you can always configure 14 of these as outputs to drive the segments directly.

Then the question becomes whether you can directly drive the segments or not. The PIC is rated for maximum 200mA sourced or sunk by the IO ports (on the smallest chip which doesn't have ports C or D available), with max 25mA sourced or sunk by an individual pin. 200/14=14.2mA, so if your segments can be supplied by something like 10mA and still give you the desired brightness, you can directly drive them with the IO pins. (Don't forget current limiting resistors!)

The display you're using specifies an average current of 30mA per segment - but you don't have to give it that much. If you use a bigger resistor to limit it to 10mA, it'll just be dimmer. Try it out and see if the brightness meets your needs. You may even find you prefer it dimmer (personally I think 30mA LEDs are usually too intense.)

If you need more current, you'll need transistors to serve as switches. 14 discreet transistors would be a lot, but you can find transistor arrays to combine multiple transistors in one package. These will be much cheaper than a specialized IC with a 2-wire interface like the MAX6955, and straightforward to interface with. You can use MOSFETs or BJTs for this application, just don't forget that the circuits are slightly different depending on which you use (BJT needs a base current limiting resistor.)

Answer (score 1):

You can drive this with 16 output pins. For example, use 2x [ULN2003A](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/uln2003a.pdf) to sink current and two MOSFETs (p-channel) to drive the anodes (such as [AO3401A](http://www.aosmd.com/pdfs/datasheet/AO3401A.pdf)). You would also need 14 resistors (one per segment).

You drive the anode A high by driving the gate of one MOSFET low, *after* updating the relevant segment data (high input the ULN2003A input = low output = LED on). Repeat with the second MOSFET and appropriate data for those segments. You want a brief time (maybe 10usec) with both MOSFETs off to prevent ghosting. You would typically share 4 bytes of memory between your program and the interrupt, so each bit would represent a segment that appears to be on or off.

You can do this conveniently with a high priority timer interrupt at ~1kHz. For a quality appearance of the display, it's important to keep the timing stable to within 5-10% of the on time or the characters can appear to flicker or vary in brightness. So upon entering the ISR, turn off the MOSFET that is on, retrieve the data for the other character, set up the ULN2003 inputs, then turn the other MOSFET on. Repeat at each interrupt, alternating the data and the MOSFET that is on. This could be expanded to more characters, for example for 8 characters you might use 4 GPIO pins rather than 2 and use an HCMOS 1-of-8 decoder with enable to drive the MOSFETs.

There are alternative approaches such as using shift registers or power shift registers to drive the segments, saving most of the 14 pins otherwise required.

---

There are also some inexpensive Chinese LED driver chips which are used in mass produced consumer goods, and that's another option which would have a lower pin count on the MCU and a lower parts count.